# Exclude a URL from mod_rewrite rule - stop redirect to home page

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I need a mod_rewrite to redirect all http requests to https, but I want do exclude one URL

Here's what I have so far in .htaccess file.

```
# force https
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/template/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

http://example.com/template/` should not be redirected. But it is being redirected to the home page.

```
http://example.com/template/
301 Moved Permanently
https://example.com/index.php
301 Moved Permanently
https://example.com/
200 OK
```

Can anyone figure out why it's causing a redirect to the home page?

Thank you!

Comment: did you clear browser cache or use incognito mode?

Comment: Yes, also checked via http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !^[A-Z]+\ /template/.*\ HTTP [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSA]
```

The .htaccess is not good. The first request `http://example.com/template/` matches the last `RewriteRule`, which is internal rewritten to `http://example.com/index.php` which matches the first `RewriteRule` and redirect to `https://example.com/index.php` permanently. The `REQUEST_URI` is rewritten internally due to the previous `RewriteRule` referencing it. The `THE_REQUEST` is the exact request header as originally received from the client. It is not updated by any internal rewrites.

> **REQUEST_URI**
>
> The path component of the requested URI, such as
> "/index.html". This notably excludes the query string which is
> available as its own variable named QUERY_STRING.
>
> **THE_REQUEST**
>
> The full HTTP request line sent by the browser to the server (e.g., "GET
> /index.html HTTP/1.1"). This does not include any additional headers
> sent by the browser. This value has not been unescaped (decoded),
> unlike most other variables below.

Comment: This resolved the issue. Thank you. Is it necessary to have a space between !^[A-Z]+\ and /template/.*\ ?

Comment: yes, the `THE_RQUEST` example: `GET /index.html HTTP/1.1` the `[A-Z]+` matches `GET`